# Jquery ajax run only for first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using ajax post in jquery by which a portion of page is built. But the problem is that it is running only once. Here is my code below

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var res;
      function on(id){
        var dat = '';
        $.ajax({
          url: 'ajax.php', //This is the current doc
          type: "GET",
          data: {a: id },
          success: function(data){
            res = data;
            data += '<div class="white" id="white" style="display:none">'; 
            var result = $.parseJSON(res);
            $.each(result, function(k, v) {
              //display the key and value pair
              dat += "<a href = 'javascript:void(0);' onclick='on("+ k +")'>"+ v+"</a><br>";
            });
            document.write(dat);
          }
        }); 
      }
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="on(8);">Get JSON data</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

After clicking on first time the page keeps on loading after showing the result. And after second click it shows error `ReferenceError: on is not defined`.

In actual it should happen that on every click on href id is passed in jquery function and based on that sql queries are run which returns data and new page data is displayed.Everytime on href click this should happen.

Comment: works fine for me here https://plnkr.co/edit/tcbHOtSL69rN7hSk3SXY

Answer (score 1):

You should really reconsider your event handling:

```js
$(function() {
  var res;
  $(".getJson").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dat = '';
    var id = $(this).data(id);
    $.ajax({
      url: 'ajax.php', //This is the current doc
      type: "GET",
      data: {a: id},
      success: function(data) {
        res = data;
        data += '<div class="white" id="white" style="display:none">';
        var result = $.parseJSON(res);
        $.each(result, function(k, v) {
          //display the key and value pair
          dat += "<a href = 'javascript:void(0);' onclick='on(" + k + ")'>" + v + "</a><br>";
        });
        $("#output").append(dat);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="8" class="getJson">Get JSON data</a>
<span id="output"></span>
```

Comment: still same problem

Comment: thats other variable used for showing output to the htmlpage dat

Comment: @smarttechy What's the output of the `ajax.php`?

Comment: @smarttechy The reason is, you started with `dat +=`, when `dat` is not even initialised.

Comment: @smarttechy Where's the output? Show na?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131642/discussion-between-smarttechy-and-praveen-kumar).